# Compute the value of a function knowing its integral

Tags: calculus, integration

If

$$x \sin \pi x = \int_{0}^{x^2}f(t)\,dt, $$

where $f$ is a continuous function, how can I compute $f(4)$ ?

Comment: I think you mean $f(t)dt$ in the integral. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By enforcing the substitution $t=s^2$ we get
$$ x\sin(\pi x) = 2\int_{0}^{x} s\,f(s^2)\,ds $$
then by differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ we get
$$ \sin(\pi x)+\pi x\cos(\pi x) = 2x\,f(x^2) $$
hence $f(4)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ by evaluating both sides at $x=2$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus 
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\int_a^{x}f(t)dt\right]=f(x)$$
in combination with the chain rule as the upper bound in the integral is $x^2$ and not $x$.

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[x\sin(\pi x) \right]=f(x^2)\left[2x \right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minor generalization of MrYouMath's formula:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}
\left[
\int_{h_1(x)}^{h_2(x)}f(t)dt
\right]=
h'_2(x)f(h_2(x))-h'_1(x)f(h_1(x))
$$
If your case $h_1(x)$ is a constant.